# Spliting Results of PHP Query into Columns

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am having a little problem getting this query to show up as four columns using PHP and HTML. I would like the $manufacturers_query to show the results in 4 columns. So irrespective of how many rows, I want the results to show up in 4 columns. Please find below the code snippet:

```
$row = 0;
$manufacturers_query = tep_db_query("select manufacturers_name, manufacturers_id from "     .     TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " order by manufacturers_name" );
while ($manufacturers = tep_db_fetch_array($manufacturers_query)) {
$row++;
echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, 'manufacturers_id=' .                 $manufacturers['manufacturers_id'] . '=' . $manufacturers['manufacturers_name'], 'NONSSL')     .     '">'. $manufacturers['manufacturers_name'] . ' <br> ';
}
echo "</a><br><br>\n";
if ((($row / 4) == floor($row / 4))) {
```

I need this to be listed in 4 columns, but don't know where I'm going wrong. I know my design is wrong, but more eyes is better than two?

Any help please? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Use modulo, more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503720/cleaner-way-of-using-modulus-for-columns

Answer (score 3):

This returns `true` every 4 rows:

```
if ( $row % 4 == 0 )
```