# Showing Product Description as Category List Description - OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spliting Results of PHP Query into Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052068/spliting-results-of-php-query-into-columns)

I have the following line of code that pulls the description from the database,

What I am trying to do is add `<br/>` to the description so that it is not shown as one long string of data.

`mb_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..'`

**Current:**

Data Data Data Data Data Data.Data Data.Data Data.Data Data

**Required:**

Data Data

Data Data

Data Data

**Full Code:**

```
            $this->data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => mb_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by doing the following:

Editing -> catelog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl

In the above .tpl document I have adjusted **line 196** within the array:

**From:**

```
'description' => mb_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..'
```

**To:**

```
'description' => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),'<p>'),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$text = 'Data Data Data Data Data';

$data = explode(' ', $text);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        echo '<br />';
    }
    echo $value . ' ';
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have placed the full code,  Do I have to split it from the current array?

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be more appropriate to use [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) e.g.

```
$text = 'Data Data Data Data Data';
echo wordwrap($text, 10, '<br />', true);
```

Result:

```
Data Data
Data Data
Data Data
```

Comment: Where would I implement the above in my mb_substr string above?

Comment: On the string, e.g. `mb_substr(wordwrap(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 10, '<br />', true), 0, 100) . '..'`

Comment: Hey it does not seem to be working how it should :( http://d.pr/i/U0CG 10 is too little

Comment: Increase the number to how many characters you want per line, 10 was just an example ;)

Comment: I have but every line does not have the same amount of char's

Comment: It doesn't have to, the second parameter is the limit/maximum per line. Also, if you set the last parameter to false, it will not break words.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that but I am still getting http://d.pr/i/mBWa no line breaks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13712/discussion-between-nomad-and-jess-mckenzie)