# Strange behavior with switch statement using dynamic numbers as case

Tags: php, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm getting very weird behavior from a switch statement that I am using inside of a while loop in PHP.

So I rewrote some code earlier that I had written in `if-else if` statements, I decided to (pardon the pun) *switch* to a `switch` statement.

This code in particular is inside of a `while` loop, it looks like this:

```
<?
    $ret  = $db->query("SELECT * from teammates WHERE `current_team`='$lineID';");
    $loop = 1;
    while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        switch($loop) {
            case 5:
                echo "</div>";
                $loop = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                echo "<div class='row'>";
                break;
            default:
                $loop++;
        }
        echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
        echo "  <img src='somesite.com/somepicture.png"></img>;
        echo "</div>";
        $loop++;
    }
?>
```

Now, this code ***works***, BUT, I am experiencing some weird behavior, and I would really like to know why it happens.

This code takes some images, puts 4 of them in a row, then starts a new row until all the images are displayed. Giving me basically a page with 4 columns of images.

As you can see in my code, there is 2 parts where it increments the `$loop` variable. The weird behavior happens when I **remove** either of these increments.

Here is some images of the behavior (I'd be happy to include any other information needed)

With **BOTH** increments:

[image]

Missing the **2nd** increment:

[image]

Missing the **switch** increment:

[image]

Comment: At first glance, I'd say it's because you're not adding a new `<div class='row'>` after closing the previous one when `$loop` is five. What happens if you remove the `break;` for `case 5` so it falls through to `case 1` and adds a new `<div>`?

Comment: Worse fizz-buzz ever ;)

Comment: @rickdenhaan that totally makes sense, but why does the 2nd increment fix that issue?

Comment: That's accidental. Like @ficuscr said, you're incrementing twice as soon as `$loop` grows beyond 1, so it never reaches `case 5` and will never reset back to 1. You're using Bootstrap and your divs have the `col-lg-3` class, and since Bootstrap uses a grid size of 12 it appears to wrap automatically after the 4th div, even though you haven't closed the `row` div yet.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Ah okay! I will try to remove the break on case 5, and maybe look into a modulus solution like ficuscr recommended.

Comment: @ficuscr I was unaware of the term "fizz-buzz" - but I agree with you! haha! This had me scratching my head but the reasoning behind it is so obvious.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Removing that break did not fix the issue, it is still happening

Comment: However, removing BOTH breaks from the switch statement does fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting by two's. You increment `$loop` twice in the same loop.

Try a simplified version...

```
<?php
$loop = 1;

do {

    echo "$loop ";

    switch($loop) {
        case 5:
            echo "CLOSE>";
            $loop = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            echo "<OPEN";
            break;
        default:
            $loop++;
    }

    $loop++;


} while ($loop < 50);


die('eof');
```

> > > `<OPEN2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44 46 48 eof`

I'd say refactor it.  Try using a modulus function instead. Think it will look better. Also `$loop = 0;` is how I like to start counting things when possible.

---

Take a look at the following:

```
$i = 0;
echo '<div class="row">';
do {
    $i++;
    echo '<div class="col-lg-3"><img src="somesite.com/somepicture.png" /></div>';
    if ($i % 5 === 0) {
        echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL; //close row - new line for readability here
        echo '<div class="row">';
    }    
} while ($i < 50);
```

You would want to add a closing row div or prevent echoing it out if no more columns are to follow. The modulus `%` operator is a great way to do things like shade alternate rows, create grids like this, or code the ["fizz-buzz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) scenario that often is asked in interviews. Please comment if you are still unclear about anything.

Or, specifically as you provided it:

```
<?php
$ret  = $db->query("SELECT * from teammates WHERE `current_team`='$lineID';");
$loop = 0;
echo "<div class='row'>";
while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    $loop++;
    if ($loop % 5 === 0) {    
            echo "</div>";            
            echo "<div class='row'>"; //***
    }
    echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
    echo "  <img src='somesite.com/somepicture.png'/>";
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Well my question was why I _had_ to increment twice, removing one of the increments broke the display. And I'm not sure how I would do this with modulus? And I agree with you with starting at 0. When I wrote the original code I wanted to make sure I was doing it right, and it was less thinking to start at 1. I suppose I should fix that now though

Comment: No problem. Gimmie a second and I'll rewrite it using that approach.

Comment: I'm pretty confused about how this works, because I don't understand how it starts a new row when the old div is closed?

Comment: Whoops.  Well in the very last example trying to fit with code you provided I forgot to open it :) see comment `//***`... so start loop opening a row, hit column count demarker and basically do a carriage return... close trailing row at end of loop. Only issue... could have an empty row at end (if results are a multiple of 5 ) if you don't account for that somehow.

Comment: Throw `modulus' as key word into searches on this topic and should help get good results... eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503720/cleaner-way-of-using-modulus-for-columns  Just variations of the same though.